# Do I need SASS or LESS to use Mixins?

Tags: css, sass, less, mixins

I have been looking around how to use mixins with regular css3, no sass or less, so I was wondering if that was possible. All I want to do is:

```
@mixin .clientred{
    color:darkred;
}
```

in a nutshell so then I could use it later

```
h1{
    include: .clientred;
    font-size: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Feel free to review the specification .. http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html (see the "Standards and Drafts" links)

Comment: downvoted? wow, and i did try, that's why I'm asking if there is a was in regular css3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS3 does *not* support any notion of mixins.

That is only available using a CSS compiler like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).  (That's kind of the whole point of using compiled CSS... if CSS had it built in, we wouldn't need the compilers.)

Comment: (The "Nope" sounded like it was to the title question, which should really be "Yes".)

Comment: this is seriously what i was looking to know, thanks, i gotta wait 4 minutes before giving you some pts